# Zabbix login error After fresh Install

Tags: zabbix

After the Web interface configurations, it goes to the login screen. I am receiving an error which displays

```
Error in query [SELECT u.userid,u.attempt_failed,u.attempt_clock,u.attempt_ip FROM users u WHERE u.alias='guest' AND u.userid BETWEEN 000000000000000 AND 099999999999999] [ERROR: relation "users" does not exist LINE 1: ....attempt_failed,u.attempt_clock,u.attempt_ip FROM users u WH... ^]
```

Comment: "ERROR: relation "users" does not exist" - what's up with database? was it created? can you access it with zabbix credentials? were there any errors or warnings during the installation?

Comment: Yes the database has been created. and I followed the instructions from the Zabbix website. I didn't recieve any errors from the install. It was installed from the repository packages. I'm using postgresql 8.4 , zabbix is 2.0, CentOS 6. Yes I can access the database with the zabbiz creds.

Comment: And if you use zabbix credentials to access the database created, does `SELECT * FROM users` work?